# Connect to databricks remotely using python and store the table query output in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, azure, databricks

I am trying to build a solution which will connect to Azure Databricks cluster remotely (outside Azure) and store the result of a query in pandas dataframe for further analysis.

*Reference link:- https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/python-sql-connector.html*

I am able to connect to databricks successfully and achieve the operation when I run from a Azure VM (*same subscription as databricks*) using below code but upon trying the same remotely (*outside Azure*) it throws following error;
**TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because host has failed to respond.**

1. Could you please advise how I can resolve this issue?
2. Am i missing any authentication steps?
3. Is there any alternate solution?

Sample code:-

```py
from databricks import sql
import pandas as pd
    
connection = sql.connect(server_hostname="<databricks-server-hostname>",
    http_path="<databricks-http-path>", 
    access_token="<databricks-access-token>")
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM TABLE', connection )
print(df)
```

Comment: check first without Pandas - as it's shown in the documentation

Comment: The error message mentioned in description is received when we run the code as mentioned in the documentation while creating the connection. Note:- it is working fine when I run from Azure vm but failing when I try it from outside Azure.

Comment: This may be due to networking...
- Look for Virtual Private network peering.
- Try telnet remotely and from azure VM to azure databricks.
(Traceroute/ping could be also be tried to see if this connectivity issue related).